# Excel Pivot count occurances under condition

Tags: excel, pivot-table

In excel, and preferably using pivot tables, I want to count the number of occurrences that have a specific value for different line items.

---

Tom   | yes
Tom   | no
Max   | n/r
Max   | yes
Max   | yes
Max   | no

---

The pivot table should have two line items (Max/Tom), one column that counts the sum of occurrences of "yes" and "no" and one column that counts only "yes". The result would be that I can say "Max has won 2 out of 3 relevant cases; Tom has won 1 out of 2 relevant cases"

I know how to do it with formulas, but was wondering if using pivot-tables is also a possibility.

Comment: Have you the capacity to add helper columns?

Answer (score 1):

If you can add helper columns I would add two, one for yes and one for no. In the yes column (assuming your data starts in cell `A1`), in `C2` type `=--(B2="yes")` then in `D2` type `=--(B2="no")`

This will return a 1 if the cell is yes or no like follows:

```
Name    Data   Yes  No
Tom     yes     1    0
Tom     no      0    1
Max     n/r     0    0
Max     yes     1    0
Max     yes     1    0
Max     no      0    1
```

Then create a pivot table, put `Name` as `Row Labels`, then in `Values` have `Sum of Yes` and `Sum of No`

http://oi63.tinypic.com/10z5j55.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Additional fields are not necessary. When creating the pivot table, set `Name` equal to your Row value and `Data` for your Columns value.  Then, drag the `Name` field into the Values area and voila!  Screenshot attached.
[image]